# How to mine a Empty Block or reject transaction?

Tags: mining, nodes, blocks

How Can a miner can mine a empty block,reject honest transactions to be added into block ; does it mean we could tweak the miner client , if yes could someone tell how it is done and what are the commands to do it?

Thanks in advance